# Are questions about software simulating card games still on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Almost posted a question because of [this answer](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/407/23526), but in my case I still [have](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> We're not the right place to ask questions about:
>
> - Computer games, try gaming.stackexchange.com
> - ...
> - Game Recommendation/Shopping questions, this includes all questions that could be phrased like:
>         Best game for ... ?
>         Which game is like ... ?

My interpretation goes like this:

> First bullet point means no questions about computer or console games that have nothing to do with card games
>
> Last bullet point is only related to card games per se. As long as I don't want an explicit shopping list, the question should be okay.

Since I'm not the authority here, I wanted your thoughts, given the examples. Note that I used Yu-Gi-Oh! in the examples because I'm familiar with it, but it could just as well be [insert card game here].

#### Example question I

> Is there software to play the Yu-Gi-Oh! TCG for free?

Possible answer:

> Yes, it is called YGOPro and is open source.

Okay (in my eyes). Note that I'm not convinced if this question would be [on-topic for arcade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

#### Example question II

> Can you list me all software to play the Yu-Gi-Oh! TCG for free?

Possible answer:

> [Incomplete list]

Not okay.

#### Example question III

> I'm having a bug in YGOPro, can you help me? [Further issue description.]

Possible answer:

> This has been fixed since [random version number].

Not okay.

#### Example question IV

> I thought [a card] was played like [this way] but YGOPro plays it like [that way], which is right?

Possible answers:

> You missed something in the description of [a card]
>
> There is [a ruling] that states [that way]

Okay.

#### Example question V

> [An official ruling] says [this], but YGOPro does [that]. What is right?

Possible answer (for all kinds of these questions and my reasoning why therefore not okay).

> Software that simulate card games would basically need a proof that they execute the rules as the rules should be executed, this is no immanent feature of card game simulators. As such, a specific implementation of the game should never be and usually is not used as an official rule reference.

### Question

**I would like a community consensus about asking such questions.** Further examples are welcome. A clarification of the text in the help center may be a good idea because not every new user looks into meta before posting a question.

Answer (score 3):

For questions 1 and 2 they are both shopping questions, therefore they are off-topic. "Is there X?" questions may not look like a shopping question, but as your answer shows it really is. The problem is that as your answer shows people aren't just answering if it exists, but the real question of "What are examples of X?".

For questions 3, 4, and 5 are all on topic. For #3 we have [established previously](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1193/are-questions-specifically-about-the-computer-version-of-a-game-on-topic) that we allow questions about electronic versions of games as long as that game has a physical version as well (so YGOPro questions are allowed since YGO has a physical game it is based on). Given that #3 is on-topic I can think of no reason to think that 4 and 5 would not also be on-topic.

Comment: I think of existence questions as "The answer is yes, and too support my claim I give you an example." A single example suffices and hence it is no shopping question. If the OP would insist on other examples, it would be clear what he meant was your version and then the question would be closed.

Comment: @SK19 In theory that can happen, but what happens in practice is we have lists of people with answers that say "Another thing that does that too is Y". I would suggest reading this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad

Comment: I would point out for the 3rd point going to the games developer is more likely to get you the answer you need (or even get the bug fixed)